# C++ get the first argument value in template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this class

```
class AssetManager
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<const std::type_info*, Asset*> assets;

public:
    AssetManager();
    virtual ~AssetManager();

    template <typename T, typename ...Args>
    bool newAsset(Args... args)
    {   
        //Get path
        if(cached(path)) { return true; }

        auto asset = new T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        assets[&typeid(*asset)] = asset;
        return *static_cast<T*>(assets[&typeid(T)]);
    }

    bool cached(const std::string& path)
    {
        for(auto asset : assets) {
          if(asset.second->getPath() == path) {
             return true;
          }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

The first argument of every Asset will always be std::string path.
I'm trying to get this value and see if it's already loaded in the list.
Asset is an abstract class.

```
class Asset
{
private:
    std::string path;

public:
    Asset(const std::string& path);
    virtual ~Asset() = default;
    virtual bool load() = 0;
    std::string getPath();
};
```

Classes inheriting Asset may have different number of arguments and as such i'm trying to capture the value of the first argument because it will always be an std::string path as you can see in the Asset class constructor.

Comment: Am I being entirely too simple-minded if I tell you to just declare an std::string argument before args, given that it's mandatory?

Comment: Yes, do that. Otherwise you cannot enforce what people choose to pass in the pack. Why bother leaving the possibility to do it wrong??

Comment: Suggest `bool newAsset(Args&&... args)` to properly support perfect forwarding.  Without the `&&`, you're always copying your arguments.

Comment: @H.Guijt I already did that and it works, but the std::string argument is already required in the Asset class for reference so this means i have to type the argument twice which is not elegant. assetManager.loadAsset<Texture>("textures/1.tga", "textures/2.tga", 512, 512); The first argument is for the loadAsset  function the rest are the arguments to be forwarded to Texture class

Comment: While following @ascheplers advice also change your range based loop to `auto&`.

Comment: @vegeta Which is more elegant: avoiding typing something twice out of an excessive sense of D.R.Y., or requiring your callers to provide the exact data you need?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But why ? Because i'm asking how to access the first argument in template parameter pack and you don't know ?

Comment: I don't think he is dishonest, just too stuck in a certain way of thinking to realize that the solution is so easy. Sometimes you really don't need a template-factory-producer-view-controller; sometimes just adding a parameter is the best answer.

Comment: BTW, return type is suspicious and should probably be `T&`. and returning `*asset` would also avoid cast and unneeded extra look up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your first argument is always an std::string, it makes a lot of sense to just declare it that way. For one thing, it solves this problem. For another, it ensures callers can never get it wrong. And if you need it in the constructor of asset as well, either pass it separately to that constructor or just declare it there as well.

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
bool newAsset(const std::string &path, Args&&... args)
{   
    //Get path
    if(cached(path)) { return true; }

    auto asset = new T{ path, std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    assets[&typeid(*asset)] = asset;
    return *static_cast<T*>(assets[&typeid(T)]);
}
```

I'm also wondering about your use of typeid; are you absolutely certain using it as a key in a map is correct? I don't see any operator<, and operator== is not guaranteed to give consistent results according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid (under 'notes'). It might be better to use `typeid.hash_code()` instead.

Comment: Guess i'll stick to this solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

- Make path a mandatory parameter, now you can refer to it when you do your `cached` lookup
- Pass the path and the rest of the arguments together to your `Asset` constructor

.

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
bool newAsset(const std::string& path, Args&&... args)
{   
    if(cached(path)) { return true; }

    auto asset = new T{ path, std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    assets[&typeid(*asset)] = asset;
    return *static_cast<T*>(assets[&typeid(T)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the marked answer is correct for the case described in the question, I recently ran into a situation where it was more convenient not to split the first parameter from the pack.

The solution I used was

```
template <typename... T>
void f(T&&... values)
{
   using FirstType = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<T...>>;
   ...
}
```

I add it here as a reference for the (admittedly rare) cases when you really need to do exactly what the question asks.

Notice that the function expects to be called with at least one argument, a call without arguments won't compile.

Comment: I'd probably write a separate template for this purpose. Wouldn't want to instantiate a heavy `tuple` just to get an element.

Comment: Good point, a template for this specific purpose would probably compile faster.